# Is 'most ugly' a correct term?

Tags: superlative-degree

My friend recently said "My parents got me the most ugly Sherry glasses I've ever seen". He is a native English speaker and said that 'most ugly' in this context is correct even though I've always only heard the superlative as "ugliest".

Comment: The uncommon usage makes for emphasis (they really were VERY ugly).

Comment: Why would it not be correct?

Comment: Part of the general rule is that two-syllable words ending in /i/ or /o/ (e.g, _pretty_ and _narrow_) form the comparative and superlative with suffixes, while other bisyllabic words use _more_ and _most_. Since _ugly_ and _pretty_ both meet the conditions, _ugliest_ and _prettiest_ are more common. But this is a rule in flux -- it seems clear that English is headed toward fewer inflections, and probably _more_ and _most_ will extend to all bisyllabic words soon enough.

Comment: I don't see anything uncommon about its usage. If I think something is the ugliest 'something' I've ever seen I may use "ugliest" or "most ugly" @Bharg Ugliest means "most ugly" and vice versa, by definition of superlative inflection:  "they express the most extreme degree of comparison," - The Farlex Grammar Book. The safest bet is to use most 'adjective', as some adjectives inflected with the superlative suffix "-est" sound strange, ie., "willingest participant"/ "most willing participant".

Comment: @sumelic This seems to be a simple question of using superlative inflection "-est" vs "most -adj-". I'm always hesitant to close vote, but I really think this is simply a duplicate as it seems it's basically asking whether one or the other should be used.

Comment: @sumelic Yes, I voted to close as duplicate, using your duplicate question link.

Comment: Possibly related:  [“Most” as an intensifier, not as a superlative](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/418091/26083) (not answered), [Is “most” an adjective or an adverb in the following phrase?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/97193/26083 "most frightful beings") and [Do I need to put “the” before “most” in this sentence?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/27021/26083) (see in particular [phenry’s answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/27021/26083#27202 "murder most foul")).